# Select2 multiple select shrinks inside bootstrap4 inline form

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2-4

Below is a snippet demonstrating my issue. The problem is that the field gets really small whenever I type in it.

```js
$(function() {
  $("select").select2({
    placeholder: "Select a word",
    width: "100%"
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/css/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<select multiple="multiple" name="word" id="word">
  <option value="1">A really long string</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

How do I prevent the field from shrinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shrinking is to do with the

`width: 100%`

The select is attempting to derive it's width from the parent container but at no point do any of the parents have a specified width.

https://jsfiddle.net/wcy2L3pj/

I put your code into that fiddle and added `style="width: 100%;"` to the `row` parent and the shrinking stops. If you experiment with moving that width definition you'll see that on every other element,  using a percentage value doesn't stop the shrinking.

However, swap the `style="width: 100%;"` for `style="width: 250px;"`, a specific pixel value, and the shrinking problem stops. This because there is a defined concrete value that the Select2 can draw from with the `width: 100%` set in its initialisation.